# Javascript highcharts code similar to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, chart.js

[Highlight charts measure between lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2julU.png)

How to get a new line between two points in the lines of x-y-axis. As seen in the image I want to get the lines representing  3x, 4x, 5x etc. in highcharts, javascript.
Kindly click on link to get better picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the plot line functionality of highcharts.

```
plotLines: [{
    color: 'red', // Color value
    dashStyle: 'longdashdot', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
    value: 3, // Value of where the line will appear
    width: 2 // Width of the line    
  }]
```

The exact link is- 
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines

Comment: Hi I tried doing it in my code, but there seems to be an error which causes it to go blank. Mine is similar to this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/  Can you edit  and show me one line please

Comment: You might have missed a , after xAxis. It is JSON @krishna